# Copy columns between tables in memory

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, copy

I process the data from a `.csv` file.

The processing builds a table in memory from the elements contained in the csv.
This table is then processed using a SQL `INSERT` statement to fill the database with the (new) values ​​it contains.

It works for all data in the database.

What I am trying to do is leave the possibility of choosing these importer columns and what others leave unchanged.

For this my idea is to create an intermediate table which will be a mixture between the initial table from the database and the imported table built on the elements of the csv file.

I have all the elements.

A `List<int>` with the index of the columns selected to be imported. An intermediate table `ResultDatatable` at first perfectly identical to that of my database. The imported table `ImportedTable` conforms to the elements of the csv.

What I can't do is replace a column in the intermediate table with a column in the imported table.

I wanted to do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MonDataSet.Tables[0].Columns.Count; i++) // Colonnes de la table de la BD
{
    if (Choix_Columns.Contains(i)) // Test si l'index des colonnes existe dans la liste de sélection
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < MonDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count; j++)// Lignes de la table de la BD
        {
            ResultDatatable.Columns[i].Rows[j] = ImportedTable.Columns[i].Rows[j]; // Je remplis la table intermédiaire des valeurs de la table importée
        }
    }
}
```

But I cannot write this code. Already because I don't have access to `Rows[index]` and moreover `ResultDatatable.Columns [i]` (but not `ImportedTable.Columns [i]`) generates an error

> Error CS0200 Unable to assign property or indexer
>   'DataColumnCollection.this [int]' - it is read-only

So how do you copy columns between two tables in memory?

The full function code:

```
private DataTable Selection_Donnees(DataTable ImportedTable)
{
        List<int> Choix_Columns = new List<int>(); // test de liste
        Choix_Columns.Add(2);
        Choix_Columns.Add(4);

        // Initilization
        DataTable ResultDatatable = new DataTable();

        connexion = CreateConnection();
        CreateTable(connexion);
        Init_Dataset_Items(); // construction de MonDataset

        ResultDatatable = MonDataSet.Tables[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < MonDataSet.Tables[0].Columns.Count; i++)
        {
                if (Choix_Columns.Contains(i))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
                    Console.WriteLine(ResultDatatable.Columns[i]);

                    for (int j = 0; j < MonDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count; j++)
                    {
                        // Setting.
                        ResultDatatable.Columns[i]...... I do not know how to do  = ImportedTable.Columns[i]..........?? ;
                    }
                }
            }

            return ResultDatatable ;
    }
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Run me through why you're doing this again? A datatable can remember row data from "before" so you can eg download all data from the db, update only some of it from a csv and then see the difference by asking a datarow for its Original vs Current versions. It even knows on a per column value level - it may be that you can leverage this mechanism rather than this intermediate system